# Which of the following subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-isomorphism

Which of the following subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic?

**A:** $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[-\sqrt{2}]$ 
**B:** $\mathbb{Q}[e^{-2i\pi/3}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2i\pi/3}]$ 
**C:** $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2i\pi/5}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2i\pi/3}]$ 
**D:** $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2i\pi/3}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[-i]$

I know that $\mathbb{Q}[-\sqrt{2}]$ **is** isomorphic since there exists a polynomial where $$\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\cong\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^2-2)\cong\Bbb Q(-\sqrt2). $$

However I'm not sure when it comes to the exponential ones.

Comment: You need to add some of your own thoughts on the problem or I fear your question will be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have added my thoughts to the bottom of the post @PeterPhipps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q} [ e^{2\pi\iota/3} ]$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing the union $\mathbb{Q} \cup \left\{ e^{2\pi\iota/3} \right\}$, and since
$$
e^{2\pi\iota/3} = \cos \frac{2\pi}{3} + \iota \sin \frac{2\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\iota \sqrt{3}}{2},
$$
therefore we can write
$$
\mathbb{Q} [ e^{2\pi\iota/3} ] = \{ p + q \iota \sqrt{3} : p, q \in \mathbb{Q} \}
$$

Similarly, as
$$
e^{-2\pi\iota/3} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\iota \sqrt{3}}{2},
$$
so we can also write
$$
\mathbb{Q} [ e^{-2\pi\iota/3} ] = \{ p - q \iota \sqrt{3} : p, q \in \mathbb{Q} \} =  \{ p + q \iota \sqrt{3} : p, q \in \mathbb{Q} \}. 
$$
Thus we have the identity
$$
\mathbb{Q} [ e^{2\pi\iota/3} ] = \mathbb{Q} [ e^{-2\pi\iota/3} ].
$$

Alternatively, note that
$$
e^{-2\pi\iota/3} = e^{-2\pi\iota/3 + 2 \pi \iota } = e^{4\pi \iota/3} = \left( e^{2 \pi \iota/3} \right)^2,
$$
which implies that
$$
e^{-2\pi\iota/3} \in \mathbb{Q} [ e^{2\pi\iota/3} ];
$$
similarly, we have
$$
e^{2\pi\iota/3} = e^{2\pi\iota/3 - 2 \pi \iota } = e^{- 4\pi \iota/3} = \left( e^{-2 \pi \iota/3} \right)^2,
$$
which implies that
$$
e^{2\pi\iota/3} \in \mathbb{Q} [ e^{-2\pi\iota/3} ].
$$

Comment: So for a pair subfields to be isomorphic they need to have the identity where they equal each other? thanks for your help !

Comment: More simply: $e^{2\pi i/3} \cdot e^{-2\pi i/3} = 1$, so the fields in B are isomorphic. In general: $\mathbb Q(\alpha) = \mathbb Q(1/\alpha)$.

Comment: Does that apply for all fields, if the product of what is in the brackets =1 then the fields are isomorphic? @JustinYoung

Comment: Yes, a field contains multiplicative inverses, so a value and its multiplicative inverse necessarily generate the same field. There is an extra complication if you look at $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ the -ring- generated by $\alpha$. In that case, you have to give an argument that $1/\alpha$ is a polynomial in $\alpha$,